# How to pass id from javascript to rails forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to pass the selected value from the drop down to `fullcalendar plugin` and the rails `form`

The select tag

```
<%= form_tag appointments_path, :html => {:id => "form-1"} do %>
  <%= select_tag(:worker_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@client.workers, :id, :name), :selected => @a, :style=>"width:170px;", :prompt => "Select Staff Member")%>
<% end %>
```

I am passing the `@a` variable by `ajax` to

```
<script>
$('#worker_id').change(function (e) {
        var a = parseInt($(this).val());
        alert(a);  
         $.ajax({
            type: "GET",        
            url:"/customers/new",
            data : { id: a },
            success:function(result){
                $('#content1').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial =>'form', :locals => ????) %>");
            }
        });          
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy');    
        RenderCalendar($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

I am not sure whether i am doing it in right way. I want to pass the value in `form` which is here:

```
<%= form_for(@customer) do |f| %>
  <%#= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="field">
    <%#= f.label :Service_Name %>
    <%#= f.collection_select :service_id, Category.where(:client_id => @client).order(:name), :services, :name, :id, :service_name %>
  </div>

<br /> <br />
  <%= f.fields_for :appointments do |builder|%>
    <fieldset>
    <% if @a!=0 %> 
    <%= builder.hidden_field :worker_id, :value=> @customer.worker_id %>
    <%= builder.hidden_field :client_id, :value=> @client.id%>
    <%= builder.label :price %>
    <%= builder.text_field :price %>
    <%= builder.label :Service_Name %>
    <%= builder.collection_select(:service_id, @a.order(:service_name), :id, :service_name, :include_blank => true, :multiple => true ) %>
   <% end %>
      <%= builder.label :appointment_date %>
      <%= builder.date_select :appointment_date %> <br />
      <%= builder.label :appointment_start_time %>
      <%= builder.time_select :appointment_start_time, ampm: true %> <br />
      <%= builder.label :appointment_end_time %>
      <%= builder.time_select :appointment_end_time, ampm: true %>
    </fieldset>
  <%end%>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
   <%= f.hidden_field :worker_id, :value=>@customer.worker_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class=>"btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly: you are trying to rerender the fullcalender jquery plugin with your ajax success callback based on the user selected from the select tag here:

```
<%= form_tag appointments_path, :html => {:id => "form-1"} do %>
  <%= select_tag(:worker_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@client.workers, :id, :name), :selected => @a, :style=>"width:170px;", :prompt => "Select Staff Member") %>
<% end %>
```

There is an inherent issue with the way you're trying to do this.  Any embedded ruby in your views will run only once at runtime.  Essentially, your escape_javascript(render partial..... will not run because any embedded ruby is done running at that point.

What you could do is keep the ajax call you already have but run the render partial code in your '/customers/new', instead of trying to call it in the ajax callback -which is after runtime

```
render :partial =>'form', :locals => ????
```

This will return the partial code with which you want to then place on the page.  With your ajax, simply place it on the page something like this:

```
success:function(result){
    $('#content1').html(result);
}
```